# How to stop click propagation when clicking on a leaflet popup?

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, mouseevent, stoppropagation

I have a popup in a leaflet map that can be closed by clicking on the 'x' in its upper right corner. How do I make the click event not propagate to the map itself?

I've tried using preventPropagate() in many places and forms, but none of them seem to work.

My latest code looks like that:

```
<div class="actions" @click="stopPropagation($event)">

(...)

stopPropagation(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
}
```

The above div (.actions) is the popup's main div.

I have also tried calling the function at a click in the popup's component tag in the parent component, but the result was the same, meaning clicking the 'x' closes the popup as expected but also results in a click event in the map that lies behind.

I use Vue and vue2-leaflet.

I appreciate any insight from you guys. Thanks!

UPDATE: actually, doesn't matter where in the popup the click happens, it always gets propagated to the map behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for reference, here's my solution:

```
<div class="actions" @click="someMethod($event)">

(...)

someMethod(e) {
  (... some code)
  return false
}
```

The command 'return false' is what solved my problem.

I tried using '@click.stop', but it gives me the '$event.stopPropagation() is not a function' error. The same happens if I run 'e.stopPropagation()' from inside the function.

Comment: Have you found any other way to do this?

Comment: No, I can't explain but sometimes this solution works sometimes it doesn't. What I'm doing now is using a state machine (in my case xstate), so that it only responds to the clicks defined by the current state. Of course it will not work for every project, but for me it is doing a pretty good job. If you need I can elaborate on that.

Answer (score 0):

Could try an [event modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)

Perhaps the `stop` modifier:

```
<div class="actions" @click.stop="closePopup">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes complete sense, but unfortunatelly doesn't work for me. The click still propagates.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me so I wrapped my l-map in a div and applied the `click.stop` to that.

```
<div @click.stop.prevent.self="">
  <l-map...>
</div>
```

It seems to me that the actual click event is parsed by the leaflet library rather than the Vue-compatible vue-2-leaflet, so the event that is received by the function doesn't have `stopPropagation` or `preventDefault` methods on the object. Thus, when Vue calls them with `.stop` or `.prevent`, the JS engine throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I figured out for my issue dealing with event handling and stopping the propagation.

e.g.

```
someReference.on("click", (evt: L.LeafletEvent) => {
    // You don't try to reference the event (evt) that is passed in
    L.DomEvent.stopPropagation; // Just call this and it kills the propagation

    // or you can call
    // L.DomEvent.preventDefault(evt);
    ...
})
```